# Is using PHP define() within a function actually useful to the caller of that function?

Tags: php, function, scope, constants

On the php.net manual page for `define()`, there's a [user-contributed note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php#109761) that suggests that you can usefully call `define()` from within a function.

Lightly paraphrasing, the suggestion is to create a function like this:

```
<?php  
function xdefine($a) {
  foreach($a as $k => $v)
    define($k, $v); 
}  
?>
```

and then to subsequently use it like this:

```
<?php
xdefine(array(
    "SECOND" => 1,
    "MINUTE" => 60,
    "HOUR" => 3600,
    "DAY" => 86400,
    "WEEK" => 604800,
    "MONTH" => 2592000, // 30 days month
    "YEAR" => 31536000,
    "LEAPYEAR" => 31622400
));
?>
```

But both my sense and my experience are that this doesn't work: after the `xdefine()` call, each of the identifiers just evaluates to its own name, not to the value that `xdefine()` supposedly bound to it.

The reason seems pretty obvious to me (i.e., because the symbols get their values as the module containing the call to `xdefine()` is being parsed/loaded), but maybe there's some subtlety I'm missing. The author of the post named his function something different, using a cute Unicode character, but I'm pretty sure that's just a cosmetic difference.

(BTW, something similar *does* work for me if I don't define a function like `xdefine()`, but rather, just run the same `foreach()` loop over the contents of the array, provided that both the loop and the array are at module scope. This is also expected behavior, from my perspective.)

So, can someone look at the [original post](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php#109761) and tell me if there's really anything to it? Or does the author just have it wrong?

(I'd post this to the referenced php.net page, but I think I will get more eyes on the question faster if I post it here instead :-)

Comment: I would hope that the use of constants is small enough that this function would be unnecessary. However, if implemented, i'd at least throw an `if (!defined($k))` in there.

Comment: A lof of user comments on php.net are terribly misguided, that one is a decent example. Sure you can define constants like that, but why? And the function name `…define` is just awful. *"just copy paste my code"*... no thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sample function works. [The scope of a constant is global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php). However, the reason(s) to do this are dubious imho.

Comment: Turns out that the function I had written to take advantage of this kind of functionality, being more complicated than the original sample, had an unrelated bug that was preventing any of my symbols from being defined. With respect to dubiousness, I'm not doing a direct mapping from names to values as in the example, but rather, defining identifiers for numeric values queried out of an existing database. This makes the values easier to work with in my code, and makes the code resilient to moving to an environment where the specific values in the database will be different.

Comment: This is useful if (later in code) you need to know if a function was called because the defined constant will be still be defined and global. If it's defined the function was called and executed up to the line where the define is. I see no other practical reason to do this. If the idea is to define vars for different environments ala: `function config_dev(){ //defines for dev here..` and `function config_production(){ //defines for production here..` that is not advisable either. Instead, put the configs for each environment in it's own file and then, include the file needed for that environ